Copy many workbooks to a single workbook. Workbooks are the same form. Copy specific cells to my workbook for review
I am working with Excel 365 web browser ran through SharePoint with a Windows laptop. I am unable to run VBAs through the web browser, so I use the Open to Desktop to run the VBA.
Workbooks are named after clients. Workbook spreadsheets are the same form and named after the employee. A client maybe seen by many employees. A workbook may contain 1 to 15 spreadsheets per workbook. 150 clients are 150 workbooks that I review 30 employee's work.
My process is to copy over certain cells from the client's workbook done by employees to a Monthly workbook. The employee's tabs from the client's workbook are appended to the monthly workbook.
Sub ConsolidateClientData()


    Dim wsCounselor As Worksheet, wsMonthly As Worksheet
    Dim clientWB As Workbook, monthlyWB As Workbook
    Dim clientFolderPath As String, fileName As String
    Dim clientWs As Worksheet, cWsName As String
    Dim lastRowMonthly As Long, i As Long, rowOffset As Long
    Dim dayService As Range, milesTraveled As Range, hoursTraveled As Range
    Dim clientName As String, typeService As String
    
    ' Path to the folder where client workbooks are stored
    clientFolderPath = "C:\Your\Path\To\ClientWorkbooks\" ' <-- Change this to your folder path
    
    ' Set reference to the open monthly workbook
    Set monthlyWB = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Loop through all the files in the client folder
    fileName = Dir(clientFolderPath & "*.xlsx")
    
    Do While fileName <> ""
        ' Open each client workbook
        Set clientWB = Workbooks.Open(clientFolderPath & fileName)
        Debug.Print "Opened: " & clientWB.Name ' For debugging
        
        ' Loop through all the sheets (counselor tabs) in the client workbook
        For Each clientWs In clientWB.Sheets
            cWsName = clientWs.Name ' Get counselor tab name
            Debug.Print "Processing tab: " & cWsName ' For debugging
            
            ' Find the corresponding worksheet in the monthly workbook by counselor's name
            On Error Resume Next
            Set wsCounselor = monthlyWB.Sheets(cWsName)
            On Error GoTo 0
            
            If wsCounselor Is Nothing Then
                ' Debugging: If the worksheet is not found, notify
                Debug.Print "No matching tab found in monthly workbook for: " & cWsName
            Else
                ' Get Client's Name (C6) and Type of Service (F2)
                clientName = clientWs.Range("C6").Value
                typeService = clientWs.Range("F2").Value
                Debug.Print "Client Name: " & clientName & " | Service: " & typeService
                
                ' Get the ranges for Day, Miles Traveled, and Hours Traveled
                Set dayService = clientWs.Range("A11:A22")
                Set milesTraveled = clientWs.Range("K11:K22")
                Set hoursTraveled = clientWs.Range("F11:F22")
                
                ' Find the last row in the monthly workbook for appending data
                lastRowMonthly = wsCounselor.Cells(wsCounselor.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                Debug.Print "Appending data to row: " & lastRowMonthly + 1
                
                ' Loop through each row (day of service) in the current client sheet
                For i = 1 To dayService.Cells.Count
                    If dayService.Cells(i).Value <> "" Then ' Skip empty rows
                        rowOffset = lastRowMonthly + i
                        wsCounselor.Cells(rowOffset, 1).Value = dayService.Cells(i).Value ' Day service provided (A11:A22)
                        wsCounselor.Cells(rowOffset, 2).Value = clientName ' Client's name (C6)
                        wsCounselor.Cells(rowOffset, 3).Value = typeService ' Type of service (F2)
                        wsCounselor.Cells(rowOffset, 4).Value = milesTraveled.Cells(i).Value ' Miles traveled (K11:K22)
                        wsCounselor.Cells(rowOffset, 5).Value = hoursTraveled.Cells(i).Value ' Hours traveled (F11:F22)
                    End If
                Next i
                
                ' Clear the wsCounselor reference for the next loop
                Set wsCounselor = Nothing
            End If
        Next clientWs
        
        ' Close the client workbook
        clientWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
        
        ' Move to the next workbook in the folder
        fileName = Dir
    Loop
    
    MsgBox "Consolidation Complete"
End Sub

Here are a few details on how I got this VBA to work. I ran the VBA on my laptop with Excel 365 and it ran through the clients' spreadsheets opening and closing them and bringing up the monthly workbook and repeating the process going through all client workbooks. The monthly workbook wasn't receiving or appending the data.
On my Windows 10 Desktop that has Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2019. The program opened the client's workbook and began copy to the monthly workbook perfectly, I just loved it. Then, tried to run it again and it hasn't worked since.
I would like for this to run on my laptop with Excel 365, it's the one I take to work every day. If not, then I would like to use my home desktop computer with Excel 2019. I will just have to bring my work home.

There are no clues in the Debug.Print output?

Consolidate From Multiple to Multiple Worksheets

The only immediate mistake I found is the destination 'row-business' i.e. replace all occurrences of lastRowMonthly with rowOffset and remove the duplicate variable declaration (Dim).
Here's what I came up with while playing around.

Standard Module, e.g. Module1, or renamed to e.g. modMain
Option Explicit

Sub ConsolidateClientData()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const SRC_FOLDER_PATH As String = "C:\Your\Path\To\ClientWorkbooks\"
    Const SRC_FILE_PATTERN As String = "*.xlsx"
    Dim SRC_CELLS() As Variant: SRC_CELLS = VBA.Array("C6", "F2")
    Dim SRC_COLUMNS() As Variant: SRC_COLUMNS = VBA.Array("A", "F", "K")
    Const SRC_ROWS As String = "11:22"
    Const DST_COLUMN As String = "A"
    
    ' Reference the destination workbook (monthly).
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code

    ' Retrieve the name of the first file (workbook) in the source folder.
    Dim SourceFileName As String:
    SourceFileName = Dir(SRC_FOLDER_PATH & SRC_FILE_PATTERN)
    
    ' Exit if no file was found.
    If Len(SourceFileName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files matching the pattern """ & SRC_FILE_PATTERN _
            & """ in """ & SRC_FOLDER_PATH & """ found!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Calculate the number of source rows
    ' to be able to define the array.
    Dim sRowsCount As Long:
    sRowsCount = dwb.Worksheets(1).Range(SRC_ROWS).Rows.Count
    
    ' Calculate the number of source (destination) columns
    ' to be able to define the array.
    Dim ColumnsCount As Long:
    ColumnsCount = UBound(SRC_CELLS) + UBound(SRC_COLUMNS) + 2 ' zero-based
    
    ' Define the array.
    Dim Data() As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To sRowsCount, 1 To ColumnsCount)
    
    ' Create an instance of the 'clientData' user-defined type.
    Dim client As clientData
    
    ' Populate its constant properties,
    ' the arrays holding the source cell addresses and source columns.
    With client
        .CellAddresses = SRC_CELLS
        .ColumnStrings = SRC_COLUMNS
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim swb As Workbook, sws As Worksheet, dws As Worksheet
    Dim dRowsCount As Long ' the number of non-blank rows to copy
    
    ' For each file apply the same logic...
    Do While SourceFileName <> ""
        ' Open the source (client) workbook.
        Set swb = Workbooks.Open(SRC_FOLDER_PATH & SourceFileName)
        ' Loop through the WORKSHEETS of the source workbook.
        For Each sws In swb.Worksheets
            ' Reference the corresponding destination sheet.
            RefWorksheet dwb, dws, sws.Name
            If Not dws Is Nothing Then ' the destination sheet was found
                ' Read from the source sheet (ranges).
                PopulateClient client, sws, SRC_ROWS
                ' Write to the destination array.
                PopulateArray client, Data, dRowsCount, sRowsCount
                ' Write to the destination sheet (range).
                PopulateRange dws, DST_COLUMN, Data, dRowsCount, ColumnsCount
            Else ' the destination sheet was not found
                Debug.Print "No sheet named """ & sws.Name _
                    & """ found in workbook """ & dwb.Name & "!"
            End If
        Next sws
        swb.Close SaveChanges:=False ' it was just read from
        SourceFileName = Dir ' read next file (workbook) name
    Loop
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Consolidation Complete"

End Sub

Standard Module, e.g. Module2, or renamed to e.g. modHelp
Option Explicit

' Indices of the Source Arrays
Private Enum sCells
    ClientName
    ServiceType
End Enum
Private Enum sColumns
    DayService
    Hours
    Miles
End Enum

' Actual Destination Columns
Private Enum dColumnIDs
    DayService = 1
    ClientName
    ServiceType
    Miles
    Hours
End Enum

' Each Client (Worksheet)
Type clientData
    ' Constant
    CellAddresses() As Variant
    ColumnStrings() As Variant
    ' Each Sheet
    Name As String
    ServiceType As String
    DayService() As Variant
    Miles() As Variant
    Hours() As Variant
End Type

Sub RefWorksheet( _
        ByVal wb As Workbook, _
        ByRef ws As Worksheet, _
        ByVal SheetName As String)
    Set ws = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets(SheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Sub PopulateClient( _
        ByRef client As clientData, _
        ByVal ws As Worksheet, _
        ByVal RowsAddress As String)
    With client
        .Name = ws.Range(.CellAddresses(sCells.ClientName)).Value
        .ServiceType = ws.Range(.CellAddresses(sCells.ServiceType)).Value
        Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Rows(RowsAddress)
        .DayService = rg.Columns(.ColumnStrings(sColumns.DayService)).Value
        .Hours = rg.Columns(.ColumnStrings(sColumns.Hours)).Value
        .Miles = rg.Columns(.ColumnStrings(sColumns.Miles)).Value
    End With
End Sub

Sub PopulateArray( _
        client As clientData, _
        ByRef Data() As Variant, _
        ByRef dRowsCount As Long, _
        ByVal sRowsCount As Long)
    With client
        dRowsCount = 0 ' reset ('ByRef')
        Dim sRow As Long
        For sRow = 1 To sRowsCount
            If Len(CStr(.DayService(sRow, 1))) > 0 Then ' not blank
                dRowsCount = dRowsCount + 1
                Data(dRowsCount, dColumnIDs.DayService) = .DayService(sRow, 1)
                Data(dRowsCount, dColumnIDs.ClientName) = .Name
                Data(dRowsCount, dColumnIDs.ServiceType) = .ServiceType
                Data(dRowsCount, dColumnIDs.Miles) = .Miles(sRow, 1)
                Data(dRowsCount, dColumnIDs.Hours) = .Hours(sRow, 1)
            End If
        Next sRow
    End With
End Sub

Sub PopulateRange( _
        ByRef ws As Worksheet, _
        ByVal Col As String, _
        Data() As Variant, _
        ByVal RowsCount As Long, _
        ByVal ColumnsCount As Long)
    If RowsCount > 0 Then
        Dim cell As Range:
        Set cell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        cell.Resize(RowsCount, ColumnsCount).Value = Data
    End If
End Sub

